# success login show me 2 message (error login & success login) pyqt5

Tags: python

i have 3 msg info for login :

field empty
error login
success login

if input Incorrect info login hes show me error login that what i want, OK Done.
if click login btn without fill a fields hes show me error msg that what i want OK Done.
but if input correct info hes show me 2 different msg, hes show me error login and success login in same time :

```
from cgitb import enable
from peewee import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit
import sys
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, maxWidth=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mysql_db = MySQLDatabase('data', user='root', password='toor', host='127.0.0.1', port=3306)
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)
        self.handel_buttons()
        self.db_connection()
        self.close_popup_error()
        self.popup_success()
        self.hide_frame()
        self.close_popup_error_empty()


    def db_connection(self):
        self.cur = self.mysql_db.cursor()
        print('connected')

    def handel_buttons(self):
 
        #### Buttons for LOGIN page ######

        self.btn_log.clicked.connect(self.page_login)
        self.btn_close_popup_empty.clicked.connect(lambda: self.frame_empty.hide())
        self.btn_close_popup_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.frame_success.hide())
        self.btn_close_popup.clicked.connect(lambda: self.frame_error.hide())


    def page_login(self):
        username = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        password = self.lineEdit_5.text()

        if len(username) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
            self.frame_empty.show() ### if fields empty show error msg 

        else:
            self.cur.execute(''' SELECT username , password FROM users''')
            data = self.cur.fetchall()

            for row in data:
                if row[0] == username and row[1] == password:
                    self.frame_success.show()  ##if username & password CORRECT show success msg 

                else:
                    self.frame_error.show() ##if username & password INCORRECT show error msg


    def close_popup_error(self):
        self.frame_error.hide()
        print('error Login ')

    def close_popup_error_empty(self):
        self.frame_empty.hide()
        print('Field empty')

    def popup_success(self):
        self.frame_success.hide()
        print('success login')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Error Field]

[image: incorrect info login]

[image: Success login]

Comment: you get all users in database and later you check `if/else` for all users - and for one of them you get SUCCESS but others you get ERROR. You should't use `else` but set error only if you finish `for` loop without SUCCESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but you get all users in database and later you check `if/else` for all users - and for one of them you get `SUCCESS` but for others you get `ERROR`.

You should't use `else` but set error only if you finish for loop without `SUCCESS`

Something like

```
# --- before for-loop ---

found = False

# --- for-loop ---

for row in data:
    if row[0] == username and row[1] == password:
        self.frame_success.show()  # if username & password CORRECT show success msg 
        found = True
        break  # there is no need to check others

# --- after for-loop ---

if not found:
    self.frame_error.show()  # if username & password INCORRECT show error msg
```

---

Python has also special contruction `for/break/else` for this.

`else` needs the same indentation as `for`, not as `if`

```
for row in data:
    if row[0] == username and row[1] == password:
        self.frame_success.show()  # if username & password CORRECT show success msg 
        break  # it needs it to skip `else`
else:  # executed when `break` was not used 
    self.frame_error.show()  # if username & password INCORRECT show error msg
```

Comment: thank you sir .. its work ♥ im used solution 2 special contruction for/break/else.. its work

Comment: solution 1  if try write incorrect info hes not show me error msg .. 
Thank you sir for help .. ♥♥